# ubuntu22+apache2+gerrit Could not open password file

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, gerrit

the environment base on ubuntu22.
apache2+gerrit base on http auth,need a password file ,it wonnot work;
the eror:
[Sun Jul 09 21:09:41.033037 2023] [authn_file:error] [pid 6303:tid 140002283005632] (13)Permission denied: [client 10.2.24.1:53254] AH01620: Could not open password file: /home/web/ger/pwd

apache2 config：

```
root@web:/etc/apache2# more httpd.conf
<VirtualHost *:8090>
    ServerName 10.2.24.136:8090
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location /login/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
        Require valid-user
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /home/web/ger/pwd
    </Location>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ProxyPass / http://10.2.24.136:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

the gerrit  file tree:

```
web@web:~/ger$ ll
total 60
drwxrwxr-x 14 web      web      4096 Jul  9 21:03 ./
drwxr-x--- 11 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:31 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:33 bin/
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:42 cache/
drwxrwxr-x  5 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:44 data/
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:42 db/
drwxrwxr-x  3 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:41 etc/
drwxrwxr-x  4 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:33 git/
drwxrwxr-x  6 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:34 index/
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:31 lib/
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:42 logs/
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:33 plugins/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   42 Jul  9 21:03 pwd*
drwxrwxr-x  2 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:31 static/
drwx------  3 web      web      4096 Jul  9 20:42 tmp/
```

the gerrit config：

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://10.2.24.136:8081
    serverId = bded22f4-98ed-4efa-87d0-43ffd3cde591
[container]
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackend
Factory#getInstance"
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getI
nstance"
    user = web
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
[index]
    type = lucene
[auth]
    type = HTTP
    userNameCaseInsensitive = false
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://*:8081/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

i try change the file owner and Read and write permissions but it not work,how can i fix it